# Sort multiple sublists of list to create new list, Dart

Tags: list, sorting, flutter, dart, sublist

I'm trying to sort an entire list according to one property. Afterwards I'd like to sort this list according to a second property, but in groups of 4. So, after sorting the list once, I want to look at the first 4 positions and sort only these 4 according to the second property - then move on to the next 4 positions and sort these again, and so on...

This is what I have so far:

```
class myElements {
  int Position;
  String text;
  int Top;
  int Left;


  myElements(int Position, String text, int Top, int Left){
    this.Position = Position;
    this.text = text;
    this.Top = Top;
    this.Left = Left;
  }
}
```

```
var FirstList = new List<myElements>();
var newList = new List<myElements>();
```

Adding Elements to my first list:

```
myElements Test = myElements(ElementNumber, text, Top, Left);
              FirstList.add(Test);
```

Then sorting for the first time according to 'Top':

```
 Comparator<myElements> TextComparator = (a, b) => a.Top.compareTo(b.Top);
      FirstList.sort(TextComparator);
```

Here is where I'm stuck. I'm trying to sort the list again, but only in groups of 4 - this time according to 'Left':

```
   for (int i = 0; i < FirstList.length; i += 4) {
          Comparator<myElements> TextComparator2 = (a, b) =>
              a.Left.compareTo(b.Left);


          newList.addAll(FirstList.sublist(i, i + 3).sort(TextComparator2)); //this line does not work
        }
```

I think I am stuck trying to access my sorted sublist: `(FirstList.sublist(i, i + 4).sort(TextComparator2)` . If I could add these to a new list, it should work. 
However any other suggestions are more than welcome.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```dart
> newList.addAll(FirstList.sublist(i, i + 3).sort(TextComparator2)); //this line does not work
> ```

Your code is almost correct.  You have the right idea, but you ended up trying to do too much in one line of code.

Breaking it down a bit, your code is equivalent to:

```dart
var sublist = FirstList.sublist(i, i + 3);
newList.addAll(sublist.sort(...)); // Does not work
```

And that doesn't work because [`List.sort`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/sort.html) does not return a value.  It *mutates* the list instead of returning a new list.

It would work if you instead did:

```dart
var sublist = FirstList.sublist(i, i + 3);
sublist.sort();
newList.addAll(sublist);
```

Also, [`List.sublist`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/sublist.html) uses an *exclusive* end index.  If you want to create sublists with 4 elements, you would need to use `sublist(i, i + 4)`.